# Does it make sense using Vue 3 reactivity on a service?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity, primevue

I have found following [DataTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/datatable/basic) code snippet by PrimeVue, that uses the new [Compositon API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html)

```
<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import ProductService from './service/ProductService';

export default {
    setup() {
        onMounted(() => {
            productService.value.getProductsSmall().then(data => products.value = data);
        })

        const products = ref();
        const productService = ref(new ProductService());
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
        return { products, productService }
    }
}
</script>
```

Does it make any sense to ref() the ProductService?
I guess it does not. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are correct, the assignment to `ref` is unnecessary.

I thought that might have been added for consistence with the options API:

```js
import ProductService from './service/ProductService';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            products: null
        }
    },
    productService: null,
    created() {
        this.productService = new ProductService();
    },
    mounted() {
        this.productService.getProductsSmall().then(data => this.products = data);
    }
}
```

However the `productService` is not part of the `data` object, so it is not reactive, and because it is a service that doesn't hold state it doesn't need to be.